# Python variable declaration and function error

Tags: python, function, python-import, importerror

I have an question about Python.

I want to use an variable inside an function but I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'BP' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```py
# File 1 test.py:
from importlib import import_module

def test():
    print(BP)
    print(BP["test2"].d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BP: (dict) = {}
    BP.update({"test2": import_module(".test2", "test_folder")})



# File 2 file2.py in test_folder:
from test import test

d: (dict) = {"Hello": "World"}

print("hi")
test()
```

So my question is: why is this not working?

Comment: The `__name__ == "__main__"` section does not execute when you import the module. If you want it to, remove the test.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem but try to avoid using filenames for your python script like test.py. When using other packages conflicts may arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

That's only true if you actually *run* the `test.py` file, *not* when you just import it, as you do from `file2.py`. In the latter case, there is no code running to bind the `BP` variable to an object, so calling `test` will complain about it.